# Переделка запроса mysql в postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Всем привет, ребята. Нужна ваша помощь. Сижу битый час и не могу составить запрос.
В общем, нужно трансформировать запрос понятный бд postgres. Исходный запрос под Mysql

Суть: запрос вытаскивает данные по часам. За каждый час считает строки и вытаскивает количество. Вроде так. timestamp содержит дату создания строки в таблице, в формате штампе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заранее огромное спасибо.

```
"SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(  `timestamp` ) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(  `timestamp` ) mod 3600 ) AS ts, COUNT( * ) AS count"
    " FROM  `system_productivity`" 
    " WHERE  `line` = $sn "
    " AND  `timestamp` >  '".$arr["start"]."'"
    " AND  `timestamp` <  '".$arr["end"]."'"
    " GROUP BY ts"
    " ORDER BY ts"
    " LIMIT 0 , 100";
```

Comment: *Исходный запрос под Mysql* Это не запрос, а издевательство над разумом... да и имена полей из той же бочки. *нужно трансформировать запрос понятный бд postgres* ```SELECT date_trunc('hour', "timestamp") AS ts, COUNT(*) AS "count" FROM ...```

Comment: Фото структуры таблицы. Вчера небыло возможности добавить. https://ibb.co/MDsHGGx

Comment: А мы не лечим по фотографиям. [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120) Сделайте нормально. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Особенно пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: добавил в основной пост

Comment: Большое спасибо. Получилось. Запрос "SELECT date_trunc('hour', timestamp_st100) AS ts, COUNT(*) AS tv_count
FROM public.system_productivity
WHERE line_fk = 1 AND timestamp_st100 >= 'Nov 07 2023 04:00:00'
GROUP BY ts"

Comment: Лучше используйте ISO-литералы даты. `.. AND timestamp_st100 >= '2023-11-27 04:00:00' ...`